# Win32 API application glitching

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, calculator, codeblocks

I am new to the Win32 API, and I tried making my own calculator, but when I run the code, the edit control starts to glitch, and I can't see what has been inputted.

I tried adding a button which stores the value 1 into the edit control (where the text of the calculator will be displayed), but whenever I use the button, or try to type directly, the text starts to glitch.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ONE_BUTTON 1
/*#define TWO_BUTTON 2
#define THREE_BUTTON 3
#define FOUR_BUTTON 4
#define FIVE_BUTTON 5
#define SIX_BUTTON 6
#define SEVEN_BUTTON 7
#define EIGHT_BUTTON 8
#define NINE_BUTTON 9
#define TEN_BUTTON 0*/




void AddControls(HWND);

HWND hOut;

HWND hOne;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst , LPSTR args, int ncmdshow)
{
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"mywindowclass";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    if(!RegisterClassW(&wc))
        return -1;

    CreateWindowW(L"mywindowclass",L"calculatorGUi",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE,100,100,500,350,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    MSG msg = {0};
    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,NULL,NULL))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

}
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wp,LPARAM lp)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wp)
        {
        case ONE_BUTTON:
            char one[50];
            char out[15];
            GetWindowText(hOne,one,50);

            strcpy(out,one);

            SetWindowText(hOut,out);
        }


    case WM_CREATE:
        AddControls(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd,msg,wp,lp);
    }
}

void AddControls(HWND hWnd)
{
    hOut = CreateWindowW(L"Edit",(int)NULL,WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER,2,2,480,106,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    hOne= CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"1",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_RADIOBUTTON|BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON 2,110,98,50,hWnd,(HMENU)ONE_BUTTON,NULL,NULL);

    /*CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"2",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,102,110,99,50,hWnd,(HMENU)TWO_BUTTON,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"3",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,202,110,99,50,hWnd,(HMENU)THREE_BUTTON,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"4",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,302,110,99,50,hWnd,(HMENU)FOUR_BUTTON,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"5",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,402,110,80,50,hWnd,(HMENU)FIVE_BUTTON,NULL,NULL);

    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"6",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,2,165,99,50,hWnd,(HMENU)SIX_BUTTON,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"7",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,102,165,99,50,hWnd,(HMENU)SEVEN_BUTTON,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"8",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,202,165,99,50,hWnd,(HMENU)EIGHT_BUTTON,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"+",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,302,165,99,50,hWnd,(HMENU)NINE_BUTTON,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"-",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,402,165,99,50,hWnd,(HMENU)TEN_BUTTON,NULL,NULL);

    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"9",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,2,220,99,50,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"0",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,102,220,99,50,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"*",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,202,220,99,50,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"/",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,302,220,99,50,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"=",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,402,220,99,50,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);*/


}
```

Comment: You should have a `return 0;` at the end of `WindowProcedure` and a `break` for the `ONE_BUTTON` and `WM_DESTROY` cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `WM_COMMAND` and `ONE_BUTTON` cases are both missing `break` statements, so whenever the Edit sends update notifications to your main window, or whenever the button is clicked, your code falls through to call `AddControls()`, creating more and more child controls on top of the previous child controls, and reusing the same child IDs.

Also, your `ONE_BUTTON` handler has a buffer overflow if the user enters text with more than 14 characters.

Try this instead:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wp)
        {
        case ONE_BUTTON: {
            char one[50] = {};
            GetWindowText(hOne, one, 50);
            SetWindowText(hOut, one);
            break; // <-- add this!
        }
        break; // <-- add this!

    case WM_CREATE:
        AddControls(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break; // <-- add this!

    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }

    return 0; // <-- add this!
}
```

Comment: Also the button also only inputs once

Comment: @AmmishaddaiBoakye First fix your existing bugs.  Then, if this is still happening, please ask a new question.